# Send HTML as body for a mailto link

Tags: jquery

When a user encounters an error in my application when using jquery ajax I want to offer the ability to send an email to the support team (optional). I have provided a simple mailto link BUT how could I send the error as part of the mail? e.g. `jqXHR.responseText`

Because I'm using .net the error has formatting and therefore I cannot do: `?body=' + jqXHR.responseText`

Any ideas? Remember I'm using jquery ajax and this all happens inside a modal.

My only real solution is to create another modal that has a mail form inside it and then mail the HTML using .net.

Comment: base64 encode it and then attach it to body :)

Comment: 1.) That would mean I would have to decode the error on the other side and 2.) You can't send base64 in a mailto apparently.

Comment: http://www.angelfire.com/dc/html-webmaster/mailto.htm have a look at this, use a form, with hidden inputs, so same thing but a bit more code, scroll down to `html mailto forms`

Comment: I really think you should just post, it to your server, all the info using `$_POST` in php and email it that way, if you wish to get the reports, you don't even have to ask users, to send you the report, you can just gather it :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to do i think.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var bodycontent = $('.div_you_want').text();
   $('.addyoursdivsclass').append("<a href='mailto:email@email.com?subject=" + bodycontent + ">LINK</a>");
});
```

I havent tested this in jsfiddle, you may need to do .html let me know if this helps.